# AVAudioSession unknown

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm, trying to use AVAudioSession in my Swift SpriteKit app. I am getting weird "undeclared type" problems. For instance...

```
import AVFoundation
var audioSession:AVAudioSession {
    return AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
}
```

This returns an error on the first instance of AVAudioSession,`Use of undeclared type 'AVAudioSession'`. Later in my code I have this line...

```
import AVFoundation
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        var titleError:NSError?
        audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: &error)
...
```

Which returns the same error on `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`. Did this stuff move in recent versions of Swift/Xcode?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Is this really an iOS project? AVAudioSession is not available on the OS X platform.

Comment: Ahhh, it's a universal project, so I guess I need to #if that code out when compiling to that target! Duh. Is there an equivalent on MacOS I should be aware of, something that has the same general effect of providing universal sound control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK this is old and I'm sure you've solved it by now, but I just ran across the same error. The issue was that I was building for Mac while AVAudioSession is (currently) only available for iOS.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/

Comment: Thanks, that likely saved me some pain.

Answer (score 6):

You should add the following at the top of your class

```
import AVFoundation
```

and make sure AVFoundation is in your "Link Binary with Libraries"